# Perl newbie: trying to find string in array of strings

Tags: regex, perl

I need to match a string against an array of strings. The string that I am searching for should be able to contain wildcards.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
##   disable buffered I/O which would lead
##   to deadloops for the Apache server
$| = 1; 
#
##   read URLs one per line from stdin
while (<>) {
    my $line = $_;
    my @array1 = ("abc","def","ghi");
    $found = 0;
    if (/$line/i ~~ @array1)
    {
        print "found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "not found\n";
    }

}
```

I test this script with the input of `abc` and it returns `not found`

```
perl ./mapscript.pl
abc
not found
```

Answer (score 3):

Your input has a newline at the end.  Add:

```
chomp $line;
```

right after

```
my $line = $_;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `chomp(my $input = $_)` to remove newline instead of `my $input = $_` inside your while..

** OOPs.. Didn't see that I'm posting Duplicate..

Answer (score 1):

a newline at the end always exists using <>. see [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)